# Platform collisions going wrong

Tags: python, pygame

Hi I'm making a platformer on pygame but I am having troubles with the collisions occuring between the player and the platforms, including the floor. The problem is that the player, when on the ground, tries to go down a pixel but is immediately put up, as the program cannot decide whether it should go up or down. Here is the code causing the problem:

```
def ground_check(self):
    if self.onGround == False:
        self.speedy += self.gravity
    if self.onGround:
        self.speedy = 0
```

This checks to see if the player is on the ground, so if onGround is False then the player should be pulled down by gravity.

```
def check_platforms(self):
    block_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, platform_group, False)
    for block in block_list:
        if self.rect.bottom < block.rect.top:
            self.onGround = False
        elif self.rect.bottom > block.rect.top:
            self.onGround = True
            self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
```

This checks for any platform collisions within the sprite group.

```
def update(self):
    self.speedx = 0
    self.onGround = False
    self.check_walls()
    self.check_platforms()
    self.ground_check()
```

And this is part of the update section that I think is causing the majority of the problems. I know what the problem is but I do not know how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you update the player's position?  And why do you set self.onGround to False before checking for collisions?  onGround should be set to True when the player collides with the top of a floor or ground.  It should only be set to False when the player jumps or walks off the end of a platform.  Your Y position shouldn't be updated unless self.onGround is false.  That way you won't have the wobble.

Comment: onGround is set to false as I want the player to fall at the beginning. I update everything else in the update but I didnt put it in as I thought it wouldnt fit in the context of the question. Thanks I'll take that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is two fold.  First, you are incorrectly setting your player to onGroud = False every update.  Why do you want to do this?

Next, you enter your check_walls() method.  I am going to assume this does nothing to they Player's Y position or movement.

Then you enter your check_platforms() method.  If you are colliding with a platform, such that your player bottom is bellow the platform top, you set onGround to True and then you set.rect.bottom to be equal to the block.ret.top.  [THIS IS WHERE YOUR ISSUE STARTS].  We are now in a condition where self.rect.bottom == block.rect.top AND neither the `if self.rect.bottom < block.rect.top:` nor `elif self.rect.bottom > block.rect.top:` get caught - so if onGround needs to be updated - too bad, it is False.

Now we enter ground_check(), which will update the Y velocity to add on gravity.

Here is why your player is bouncing.

Pass 1:
Update Position based on speed (code not present)
Draw sprite (code not present)
Run through Update.
  - The player collides with the platform, 
  - Reset his position to the pixel on the platform.
  - Give no Y velocity.

Pass 2:
Update Position - no change since there is no Y velocity.
Draw sprite - no change.
Run through Update.
  - Set onGround to False
  - Check Planforms - collides with block because self.rect.bottom == block.rect.top, but no action take.  Still onGround == False.
  - Update speed in ground-check.

Pass 3:
Update Position - player drops.
Draw sprite - now "in platform"
Run through Update.
  - Set onGround to False.
  - Collides with block, reset position of self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
  - onGroup == True
  - Update speed to 0.

Pass 4:
Update position - player jumps up a few pixels.

Rinse and repeat every four cycles.

The easy solution should be to change the following line of code in check_platforms:

```
elif self.rect.bottom >= block.rect.top:
```

You deleted your previous question so I can't see what my previous comment was.

Comment: What should I exactly change it to?

Comment: I believe you should change  `elif self.rect.bottom > block.rect.top:` to `elif self.rect.bottom >= block.rect.top:`

Comment: When I do self.onGround = True gravity does not function, why? So how do I fix this?

Comment: Because you are on the ground.  You don't wan to change your Y position if you are on the ground.  Think about real life.  If you are standing on the ground are you falling?